# Instagram: How to get Username/ID from Access-token?

Tags: api, token, instagram, userid

I got an access-token of an Instagram-Account on my MySQL-Database and I wanted to know if there is a way to get the Username or the UserID of the creator of this token (with PHP).
Any ideas or is this impossible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796349/instagram-how-to-get-my-user-id-from-username

Comment: @aldanux I want to get the Id/Username from an access-token (who created it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?access_token=[VALUE]

Seems to work even though it's not documented.

Comment: tested yesterday, not working anymore, can use this instead https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user

Comment: This link came in handy to me, thanks https://instagram.com/users/self