# Get Instagram user profile picture from username

Tags: javascript, authentication, instagram, instagram-api, user-profile

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33783840/4414003) contains a method by which an Instagram user's images can be obtained from their username without authenticating as a user (using the https://instagram.com/[USER_ID]/media URL). I'm looking for a similar way to obtain a user's profile picture *without authentication as a user*.

Usually, requests to `/media` contain a link to the user's profile somewhere, but these links all return 500 errors for me.

What's the best way to get a user's profile picture from their username? I'd like to do this from client-side JS if possible, so solutions involving HTML parsing are sub-optimal

Comment: the response has user profile pic url, `items[0].user.profile_picture`, its not official API and does not support JSONP, so cannot call it client side.

Comment: There is a pretty good answer about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38342137/6825980).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526137/my-app-was-rejected-by-instagram-basic-display-api-review-due-to-invalid-reasons