# How to get User ID by InstaSharper

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api, instasharp

I'm learning InstaSharper, but I can't understand how to Follow/Unfollow user. Because `UnFollowUserAsync` requires UserId. Can you tell me please how to get User's ID, or maybe there are other ways to follow/unfollow users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram how to get my user id from username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796349/instagram-how-to-get-my-user-id-from-username)

Answer (score 1):

`Pk` returns user Id in `InstaSharp`.

```
       IResult<InstaUserInfo> a = await 
api.GetUserInfoByUsernameAsync(/*username*/"asfasv");
        var id = a.Value.Pk;
```

> Other Example:

```
var nextUri = UriCreator.GetUserFollowingUri(user.Value.Pk, _user.RankToken, searchQuery,
                            userListResponse.Value.NextMaxId);
```

For more details: [UserProcessor](https://github.com/MahStudio/InstagramAPI/blob/master/InstagramAPI.UWP/InstaAPI/API/Processors/UserProcessor.cs)