# I need to get an Instagram User ID# for use in Google Script

Tags: javascript, java, json, google-apps-script

I'd like to take a username and plug it into this format

```
https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1
```

thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796349/instagram-how-to-get-my-user-id-from-username) for that tip

I then need to follow that link in java, and when doing so it presents the following page code, which I've abridged to save space. I used professional Skateboarder Nyjah Huston as my example.

```
{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_8223552","show_suggested_profiles":false,"show_follow_dialog":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"Sender\ud83d\ude08\n@nikesb @monsterenergy @elementbrand  @blackplaguebrewing @socialcbd @priverevaux","blocked_by_viewer":false,"restricted_by_viewer":null,"country_block":false,"external_url":"https://www.nike.com/t/sb-nyjah-free-skate-shoe-oKwn7N/AA4272-300","external_url_linkshimmed":"https://l.instagram.com/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nike.com%2Ft%2Fsb-nyjah-free-skate-shoe-oKwn7N%2FAA4272-300&e=ATMW9Q8NwN2Mcwm_Bd5I8DeuAKP4L7IHpy_PdylDnGU8qqokJU6Z1kh_emEIVfJ1q8Xtq1b0&s=1","edge_followed_by":{"count":3969537},"followed_by_viewer":false,"edge_follow":{"count":694},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"Nyjah Huston"
```

As you can see, the User ID is one of the first things on the page

```
{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_8223552"
```

the user id being 8223552 in this case. I'm quite new to java, and I need to know how to follow that link and parse that data in order to turn the user id into a var for use in my google script. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would suggest that you add the code you already created. Below I added my answer as guide on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parse this JSON content to a object that has only the information you need:

```
class UserInformation{
    private String logging_page_id;
}
```

I suggest this option because if you need in the future to get another info, you can easily just extend the object.

How to do the conversion, please reference to this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new to JSON and need to brush up on parsing page data like this and making calls

Comment: No problem. Good luck, @Chrslxndr.