# Instagram api working on localhost but not working on server (Instagram profile details)

Tags: php, node.js, curl

If I run this code on my localhost through terminal or Insomnia. It is just working fine. But the server return null. What should I do to get the result?

```
curl -s 'https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=alanarblanchard' -H 'X-IG-App-ID: 936619743392459' | jq -r .data.user.id
```

Comment: That doesn't look like anything from the current, official API for use by 3rd-party developers.

Comment: @CBroe I am using Instagram Basic display API. But I need to bring Profile information like BIO and followers. Not able to get this data by using this API. So I have found it tried to fetch data. This is working on my localhost with Insomnia but not working on liver server. Any suggestion?

Comment: _"Not able to get this data by using this API."_ - okay, so there is your stopping point then. If Facebook _wanted_ you to be able to access this data, then they would have made it available via the new, official API.

Comment: `X-IG-App-ID: 936619743392459` - pretty sure that is the internal ID of one of their official apps. You, as a 3rd-party developer, were never meant to use this for your own projects.

Comment: _"This is working on my localhost with Insomnia but not working on liver server."_ - most likely Facebook has caught on to your server IP address repeatedly trying to "impersonate" the official app by now, and therefor blocked it. And locally, you probably have a dynamic IP, which it why it still "works" there.

Comment: I guess you took the cURL command from my answer, which was updated to mention you may need to send cookies when using a web host: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796349/instagram-how-to-get-my-user-id-from-username/72533638#72533638

Answer (score 0):

Instagram doesn't allow requests from an unknown host. The workaround for this is to add the cookie in the request header